# jQuery dynamic table row count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have table as below

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="button" id="btnAddGatePass" value="Add Gate Pass Requester" />
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="gatePass" class="table table-striped table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Nationality</th>
                    <th>Job Title</th>
                    <th>Passport No.</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and on add click I am calling below function

```
$("#gatePass tbody").append(
        "<tr>" +
        "<td><input type='text' id='txtName' class='form-control'/></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' id='txtNationality' class='form-control'/></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' id='txtJobTitle' class='form-control'/></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' id='txtPassportNo' class='form-control'/></td>" +
        "<td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk btnSave forestgreen'>&nbsp;</span><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash btnDelete black'>&nbsp;</span></td>" +
        "</tr>");

$(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
$(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
```

and on submit button click I am counting row **but is always giving me zero** what can be the issue

```
if ($('#gatePass >tbody >tr').length === 0) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: what is the reason for down vote. Please justify it.

Comment: I suggest you check the elements with developer tools in chrome

Comment: Didn't you find `Save is not defined` ?

Comment: No actually I am not doing check on save button of table but I am doing on the button outside table

Comment: where is the button submit located..??

Comment: last code snippet is of submit button

Comment: You need to re-initialized the button event, because your adding elements dynamically??

Comment: How can we do that ? Kindly can you guide me

Comment: I try, but I cannot find any buttons in your code other than `btnAddGatePass`

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/1temcaza/

Comment: @RayonDabre I am same thing as shown in jsfiddle but still it is not working

Comment: @Malvolio there is button is my original code I just did not add over here

Comment: @Milind, If fiddle is working as expected, you can compare things....

Comment: oooooooooopsssssss I am stupid I was writing wrong table id the code thank you all

Answer (score 3):

Try the code below:-

```
var rowCount = $('#gatePass tr').length;
```